# SQL returning multiple variables

Tags: sql, case

I am trying to write a query with a case statement. I am having problems outputting my case statement as multiple variables. Basically I want to take 1 column and out put the first part as outputcolumn1 "FIRST" and the last 4 characters as outputcolumn2 "LAST"

I tried doing some research but I am not finding anything to address my flavor...
I know I am overlooking something really dumb.

```
Select *
Case When a.col_1 is NULL 
-- Grab all but last 4 as "FIRST"
Then LEFT(b.col_1, len(b.col_1) -4
-- Grab Last 4 as "LAST"
AND RIGHT(b.col_1, 4)
Else LEFT(a.col_1, len(a.col_1) -4
AND RIGHT(a.col_1, 4)

end as FIRST,LAST

From Table_1 as a
inner join Table_2 as b on a.TableID = b.TableID
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, there is a missing right parentheses here : `LEFT(b.col_1, len(b.col_1) -4`

Second, you cannot return two columns, use two case statements.

```
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN a.col_1 IS NULL 
            THEN LEFT(b.col_1, LEN(b.col_1) -4) 
            ELSE LEFT(a.col_1, LEN(a.col_1) -4)
       END AS FIRST,
       CASE WHEN a.col_1 IS NULL 
            THEN RIGHT(b.col_1, 4) 
            ELSE RIGHT(a.col_1, 4)
       END AS LAST
FROM Table_1 AS a
INNER JOIN Table_2 AS b 
ON a.TableID = b.TableID
```

I would suggest you another syntax:

```
SELECT *,
       COALESCE(LEFT(a.col_1, LEN(a.col_1) - 4), LEFT(b.col_1, LEN(b.col_1) - 4)) AS FIRST,
       COALESCE(RIGHT(b.col_1, 4), RIGHT(a.col_1, 4)) AS LAST
FROM Table_1 AS a
INNER JOIN Table_2 AS b 
ON a.TableID = b.TableID
```

Comment: I started to nest the case statements like you have here but knew I was still missing something. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help.